# sample texts for a template

Tags: templates

I am looking for some sample text, or a sample document which includes most basic LaTeX code structures such as sections, paragraphs, item lists, equations, tables, figures. I would like to include it in my template to show how it will be printed. It should be more than 3 pages so that the effect of headings become visible. And it should make some sence. Currently I only have lispum texts, which is not optimal.

So far I only found these:

- http://sip.clarku.edu/tutorials/TeX/intro.html
- https://pangea.stanford.edu/computing/unix/formatting/latexexample.php

Since this will be published in a public code repository and the template be available for everyone I must of course have the right to use and publish the text.

Comment: You can also use `kantlipsum` package for more sensible text.

Comment: I would prefer a rather technical text and I want to include the text directly in a tex file, not generate it with a command. The user of the template shall be able to find the code that produces the output directly.

Comment: And the site I provided doesn't work for you?

Comment: @percusse: at least it seemingly does not have less sense than original works of Kant;).

Comment: I think I will use both sources I included in my post and create something new based on it.

Answer (score 9):

You can use the funny thing called SCIgen, purpose of which is to generate non-sense computer-science articles that you can try to publish in a journal or a conference. On the other hand, they allow you to download not only the PDF file, but the LaTeX source file as well (including graphs, figures, tables, etc.)

You can find it here: http://pdos.csail.mit.edu/scigen/

I forgot to add: The site claims: *The code for SCIgen is released under GPL.* Which should mean that you can use the result and license it undel LPPL with no hesitation (you should just consider citing the source).